# Two Classes have same XML type name

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb

Im having this error where it says that i have two classes of same XML type name

so the problem is between InfoSource -> NameSearchFilters -> SearchRequest

**error**

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://test.au/schema/namesearch}InfoSource". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at au.test.identitySearch.model.InfoSource
        at protected au.test.identitySearch.model.InfoSource au.test.identitySearch.model.nameSearch.NameSearchFilters.infoSourceList
        at au.test.identitySearch.model.nameSearch.NameSearchFilters
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at au.test.identitySearch.model.InfoSource
        at protected au.test.identitySearch.model.InfoSource au.test.identitySearch.model.nameSearch.NameSearchFilters.infoSourceList
        at au.test.identitySearch.model.nameSearch.NameSearchFilters
        at protected au.test.identitySearch.model.nameSearch.NameSearchFilters au.test.identitySearch.ws.model.SearchRequest.searchFilters
        at au.test.identitySearch.ws.model.SearchRequest
```

**InfoSource**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "InfoSource", propOrder = {
    "infoSource"
})

public class InfoSource {

    @XmlElement
    protected List<String> infoSource;
```

**NameSearchFilters**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "NameSearchFilters", propOrder = {

})
public class NameSearchFilters {

    @XmlElement
    protected InfoSource infoSourceList;
    @XmlElement
    protected String nameType;
```

**SearchRequest**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "searchControls",
    "searchCriteria",
    "searchFilters"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "searchRequest")
public class SearchRequest {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected SearchControls searchControls;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected NameSearchCriteria searchCriteria;
    @XmlElement
    protected NameSearchFilters searchFilters;
```

Why is there problem here?

Comment: When does your code fail, during context creation? It does not fail on my box, but I do not have the class NameSearchCriteria available. Maybe you can post that as well?

Comment: the application works accross multiple teirs and works correctly when not deployed, the issue is when deploying to a server(local tomcat in this case) when my marshaller is called.

Comment: Understand, do you run different JDKs/JREs on the systems? I might be the JAXB version causing trouble...

Comment: im sure i only have one JDK and JRE on the system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try adding different values of namespace attribute to each of them like `@XmlType(namespace="test1", name = "InfoSource", propOrder = { "infoSource" }) )` ?

Comment: i have tried this it fixed one c=ount of the issue, changing name to namespace in InfoSource fixed its issue, it does not fix the last count of the issue.

Comment: this did end up solving the issue when namespace changes were reflected throughout the project (XML scheme)

Answer (score 2):

Situation like this throws exception 'x counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions'

class A{}
class B extends A{}
class C extends A{}

Resolve problem adding annotation into class A like this:

@XmlTransient
public class A
{}

Answer (score -1):

@XmlType(name = "Info_Source", propOrder = {
    "infoSource"

Try this in code