# spring boot app JAXB error "Two classes have the same XML type name"

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb

I am getting this error in my spring boot app:

> Two classes have the same XML type name
> "{xyz}OperatingSystemFamilyType". Use @XmlType.name and
> @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.

These are jaxb classes that I don't have access to, so the solution that it recommends above doesn't work. This is a bean I create and it fails at `setContextPaths`:

```
public Jaxb2Marshaller amqpMessageMarshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPaths("abc.jaxb", "efg.jaxb");
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    properties.put(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(properties);
    return marshaller;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two Classes have same XML type name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274912/two-classes-have-same-xml-type-name)

Comment: No it doesn't work in this case. He has access to the classes and add namespace to them. In my case, these are 3rd party classes that I don't have access to. :(